# Can't add more $_GET variables to the link

Tags: php, variables, get

Good afternoon,

I'm just trying to add one more variable to my link.
For example:
I am on page /article?id=12 and I want to switch it to another language. I have two links in the menu. CS and EN. But they are set to *"?lang=cs"* and *"?lang=en"*. So when I click to switch the language, it will take me to the page */article?lang=en* , but I won't have there its ID anymore. Is there any way to keep that $_GET variable and just add one?
I though I could give there *"&lang=en"*, but when I am for example on page /contact , it won't work for me like *"/contact&lang=en"*...

Thank you for all advices!

EDIT

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') != false)
{
  $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '&lang=cs';
   $url2 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '&lang=en';
}
else
{
  $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?lang=cs';
    $url2 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?lang=en';
}
```

Comment: even this: `<?
$cs = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?') === false) ? '?lang=cs' : '&lang=cs';
$en = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?') === false) ? '?lang=en' : '&lang=en';
?>` didn't work.. I have no idea how to make it work...

Comment: afaik the `REQUEST_URI` does not contain query parameters. You may want to use another variable. Use `<?php phpinfo();` to get an overview what global variables exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url = "?" . http_build_query($_GET) . (count($_GET) > 0 ? "&" : "") . "lang=en";
```

This takes the original arguments.

Comment: Thank you, that work's ! But when I have for example... 
_/article?lang=en&id=5_ and I want to switch language, it makes the link like: _/article?lang=en&id=5&lang=cs_

Comment: Do an `unset($_GET['lang']);` before if this is not necessary later on. Otherwise you have to copy `$_GET` in a local variable and unset the index `lang` there.

Comment: @HSturma: By the way, it is not nice, but your url works also :-)